# openid consumer for gwt

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, openid

Anyone have or know of a java implementation of an openid relying party(consumer) for gwt/gae?
openid4java and joid bring in too much baggage for my needs.

Comment: Be very careful about an attitude of "minimalistic" openid implementations.  Most such implementations that I've seen have enormous security holes.  The time-tested libraries are a safer bet unless you do your own thorough security review.  Not all security holes are obvious even after years of working with OpenID.

Comment: good point. I've started to lean towards a time-tested library.

Comment: can't use joid with gae; it uses restricted classes.

Comment: Amazing how GAE doesnt come with its own OpenId java client given Google are a recognized OpenId provider.

Comment: @mP - GAE has support for OpenId in 1.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine recently started supporting openID.  See the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview.html) for details.
This just happened in release [1.3.4](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes) of the sdk.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 1.3.4 Google App Engine is supporting authentication via OpenID (in addition to OAuth) out of box.

Have a look at the application registration page. The OpenID is reffered to es "Federated Login" and is currently still marked [Experimental] ... but it's working ... and the API looks almost too simple to be real ;-)

There is a GWT demo application running on http://super-easy.appspot.com

Comment: I ended up switching to the User service's openid. It was nice to drop the third party dependency and it's dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

jopenid (hosted on Google code) is very minimalistic in its dependencies (which I like) but it doesn't look to support OpenID 1.1 - which I understand is what you need from your use of the term "consumer" (compare with OpenID 2.0's "relying party").

dyuproject (also from Google code) implements more protocols including OpenID 1.1 but requires some additional dependencies.

Comment: Which product did you finally choose, and can you please explain why ?for benefit of the audience :-)

Comment: I've actually pushed off openid integration, so I've not chosen one yet.

Comment: I finished implementing openid integration yesterday. I started off using openid4java, then switched to jopenid.

Comment: I ended up switching to the User service's openid. It was nice to drop the third party dependency and it's dependencies.